# Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, https://localhost:3306/dcbapp

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I am following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3gKseNAs9w) for spring boot I did everything exactly like the tutorial and I'm getting the following exception

the exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, https://localhost:3306/dcbapp
```

My application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=https://localhost:3306/dcbapp
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

[the schema dcbapp exists in mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5ncv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `https://localhost:3306/dcbapp` is wrong.

You have to use the correct one.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dcbapp
```